# Cartesian application software recommendation in Debian

Tags: debian, software-rec, application, math

Is there a software recommendation for an application for the Cartesian field in Debian?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for software recommendation. Better ask it here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoGebra is a dynamic geometry program. You can do constructions with points, vectors, segments, lines, conic sections as well as functions and change them dynamically afterwards. On the other hand, equations and coordinates can be entered directly.

To install GeoGebra in all currently supported versions of Debian open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install geogebra
```

Another computational and plotting application that is available in all currently supported versions of Debian is *maxima* which can be installed with `sudo apt install maxima`.